# RegEx matching in JUnit for time zone

Tags: java, regex, junit

So I'm trying to verify the time zone section of a dateTime using a regex just for the "GMT" or "UTC" section.  A valid String looks like:

```
"Wed, 8 Feb 2016 11:20:00 [GMT]"
```

I've tried the following but its not working.  I've tried a bunch of different escape sequences but to no avail.

```
assertTrue(dateTime.getDateTime().matches("Wed, 8 Feb 2016 11:20:00 [\\w{3}]"));
```

I think the problem I'm having is due to the square brackets that I need being treated as part of the regEx.

Comment: should escape `\\[\\w{3}\\]`

Comment: make sure you have the input that u have shown and tested as true `"Wed, 8 Feb 2016 11:20:00 [GMT]".matches("Wed, 8 Feb 2016 11:20:00 \\[\\w{3}\\]")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `[]` because `[]` represents a list which is used to find the match so use it like `Wed, 8 Feb 2016 11:20:00 \\[\\w{3}\\]`

`\\[\\w{3}\\]`

`\\[`:  match `[` character

`\\w{3}` : match 3 times `\\w` ,`\\w` mean `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

`\\]` : match `]` character

```
    String date= "Wed, 8 Feb 2016 11:20:00 [GMT]";
    System.out.println(date.matches("Wed, 8 Feb 2016 11:20:00 \\[\\w{3}\\]"));
```

[Oracle Regex Character Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html)